# Do not how to convert to class "POSIXct"

Tags: r, lubridate, posixct

I'm trying to convert character string to POSIXct in order to use lubridate to round times to the nearest quarter hour.  Below is code:

```
x <- c("8:00", "14:47", "21:13", "01:47", "00:19")
x <- paste0(x, ":00")
x <- chron(times. = x)
as.POSIXct(x, "%H:%M:%S")
```

I get the following

Error in as.POSIXct.default(x, "%H:%M:%S") :
do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXct”

Comment: Without a "date" component of a timestamp, they cannot be `POSIXt`. Period. You can either arbitrarily assign a date or stay with a non-base-R class.

Comment: Perhaps `as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), chron::chron(times. = "08:00:00")))`

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the times into minutes, then `round` them to full fifteen minutes and convert numeric times to `POSIXct`. Finally `strftime` gives you the desired formats.

```
x <- c("8:00", "14:47", "21:13", "01:47", "00:19")
tmp <- t(sapply(strsplit(x, ":"), as.numeric))
minutes <- tmp[,2] + tmp[,1]*60
strftime(as.POSIXct((round(minutes/15)*15)/(15*4)*60^2, 
                    origin=Sys.Date(), tz="GMT"), "%H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
# [1] "08:00:00" "14:45:00" "21:15:00" "01:45:00" "00:15:00"
```